# How to inform Jenkins pipeline to use credentials from pipeline defintion?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have an issue with git command from Jenkins pipeline. Sometime users use git fetch or git push without **withCredentials**.
For historical reasons, an option was set on the Jenkins nodes:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

This option probably breaks main authentication with Github Enterprise. Sometimes an error occurs:

```
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/org/project'
```

or

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h https://github.com/org/project.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/org/project.git/'
```

There is GitHub App as credentials.

Disabling the option **credential.helper=cache** helps for this issue but breaks other pipelines.

I made sample pipeline and I confirmed this error. The credentials from pipeline definition are not used. Unless in the first stage I use:

```
git config credential.helper "cache --timeout=3600"
```

This is a workaround and I don't want to use it unless I have to, because there is a lot of pipeline, mostly multibranch kinds.

Is there any way to have the same credentials from the pipeline definition used in the pipeline itself or do I have to add these workarounds or use the **withCredentials** step?

If I were to use withCredentials then how do I use it regardless of the credential type: ssh private key, github app, or simple username/password?

Or was it generally done wrong from the beginning? Missing **withCredentials** in pipelines etc.